# How to solve nested ODE equations

Tags: r, ode

We can use the `deSolve` package in R for ordinary differential equations (ODE), however, I can't find a way to solve two nested ODE equations, suppose `

```
b'(t) = beta - k*b(t); 
a'(t) = alpha -b(t)*gamma;
```

where `'` means differentiation. How can we solve `a` and `b` then? as `a'` is a function of `b`, we have to solve `a` and `b` simultaneously.

I got an error:

> Error in lsoda(y, times, func, parms, ...) :   The used combination of solvers cannot be nested.

When I tried to add the solve for `b` inside the ode solution for `a`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I may be confused, but you seem to be describing **coupled** equations, which `lsoda` can handle perfectly well, as follows (I implemented your ODEs but made up some parameters since I didn't know what you had in mind.)

```
gfun <- function(t,y,parms,...) {
  ## 'with' trick lets us write gradient in terms of variable/parameter names
  with(as.list(c(y,parms)),
       list(c(b=beta-k*b,a=alpha-b*gamma),NULL))
}

library(deSolve)
L1 <- lsoda(y=c(b=1,a=1),
            times=seq(0,10,by=0.1),
            func=gfun,
            parms=c(alpha=0.1,beta=0.2,gamma=0.05,k=0.01))

matplot(L1[,1],L1[,-1],type="l",lty=1,bty="l",las=1)
```

PS: this seems to be a set of coupled linear ODEs, so you should actually be able to get a full closed-form solution rather than solving them numerically. (I'm too lazy to do that right now; b(t) can be solved immediately (an "affine" equation), a(t) can be solved by integration.)

Comment: thanks a million, Ben. I have to solve numerically as the actual problem is a harder multivariate issue and I can't derive a closed-form solution.